# "Projecting" generally placed hyperplane, still generally placed?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q} \renewcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}$Suppose I have $4$ hyperplanes (defined over $\Q$) that are in general (linear) position in $\P^n(\Q)$ with $n\geq 2$. I suspect that I can always find a two dimensional linear space in $\P^n$ such that intersecting the hyperplanes with it will yield lines that are still in general position. It sounds like a "trivial" result in linear algebra, what is the fastest way to prove this if it is true? What if I substitute $4$ with any number greater than $3$? I don't suppose $\Q$ plays any role here so we may as well substitute it with any field $K$.

Comment: Suppose you have two lines in general position in the plane. Can you find a projection down to the $x$-axis which takes those two lines to two points? Do the same with two planes in $\Bbb Q^3$, attempting to project to two lines in the $xy$-plane, or two points on the $x$-axis. I would rather suspect that it cannot be done. Is projective space really that different?

Comment: I think I should say intersection with a linear space isomorphic to $\mathbb P^2$ rather than projection.